# Springdoc - How do I add externalDocs to OpenAPI swagger UI auto generated documentation

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

So I have a spring boot project that I just added OpenAPI Swagger UI to. It auto generates the documentation really well for all of our controllers and models. But I would like to add some additional configuration such as externalDocs as shown here.

```yaml
externalDocs:
    url: URL
    description: DESC
```

But since its auto generated I don't have a YAML for swagger. I tried the following to add it through a Bean with no luck.

```java
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.ExternalDocumentation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.License;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

public class springShopOpenAPI{

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI springShopOpenAPI() {
           return new OpenAPI()
            .info(new Info().title("SpringShop API")
            .description("Spring shop sample application")
            .version("v0.0.1")
            .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0").url("http://springdoc.org")))
            .externalDocs(new ExternalDocumentation()
            .description("SpringShop Wiki Documentation")
            .url("https://springshop.wiki.github.org/docs"));
    }
}
```

Below is my Pom.xml if needed.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.28</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you using any framework like Springdoc etc.?

Comment: I'm using springdoc-openapi-ui v1.2.28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I needed to do was add `@Configuration` and update my pom.xml to have the following.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.ExternalDocumentation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.License;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class springShopOpenAPI{



    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI(){
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info().title("SpringShop API")
                        .description("Spring shop sample application")
                        .version("v0.0.1")
                        .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0").url("http://springdoc.org")))
                .externalDocs(new ExternalDocumentation()
                        .description("SpringShop Wiki Documentation")
                        .url("https://springshop.wiki.github.org/docs"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

If somebody is trying to add a link to a `@Tag`, for linking to a wiki page for instance, this can also be done with the `externalDocs` keyword as follows :

```java
@RestController
@Tag(name = "MyController",
     description = "MyController goal is ...",
     externalDocs = @ExternalDocumentation(description = "Wiki page about MyController.", url = "https://confluence.mycorp.com/display/..."))
public class MyController { ...
```

Comment: This also works on `@Operation`, if you just wanna add links to different endpoints directly - use it w/ `@Operation`

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to implement the `OperationCustomizer` interface to add external links. The code should look something like below

```java
@Component
public class EndpointCustomizer implements OperationCustomizer {

    @Override
    public Operation customize(Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
        // Will add the externalDocs to all the endpoints
        operation.externalDocs(new ExternalDocumentation().url("/resource").description("Link to resource"));
        
        return operation;
    }
}
```

You can also perform additional logic to add the `externalDocs` based on certain criteria.
Once the class is defined, you'll need to create an API Group in the class where you are defining your OpenAPI Bean (the `springShopOpenAPI` class in your case).

```java
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi hideApis(EndpointCustomizer endpointCustomizer) {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("default") // or use null instead of default
            .addOperationCustomizer(endpointCustomizer)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Where do I a dd the bean if I dont have a class that creates the OpenAPI Bean? Or whaty should the OpenAPI bean classlook like>

Comment: @Dylan in your case that class already exists, i.e. `springShopOpenAPI`. There you have a bean that returns an `OpenAPI` object. That's what I was referring to.

Comment: I get an error that group has private access but changing it to setGroup means addOperationCustomizer doesnt exist

Comment: You should use `group` and not `setGroup`. If you take a look at the source, you'll know that `setGroup` is deprecated, and `group` should be used instead. And for the private issue, please share a github gist for both the files you made.

Comment: For further discussion, we can continue in the following chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220444/springdoc-clarification